# What reason was Madara talking about in Chapter 661 ?

Tags: naruto

Madara says that there is a reason why Hashirama and Tobirama can't bring out their true strength, what was he talking about ?

Comment: IIRC, he thinks that they can't use their full power since they are Edo Tensei-ed. Means that their power is limited by the caster of the Edo Tensei,

Comment: To build on Ayase Eri's comment, Orochimaru was said to have taken the 2nd's jutsu to usable scale, but Kabuto sort of perfected it. Thus Madara may be commenting about the level of Kabuto and Orochimaru's difference. Though breaking out of the Edo Tensei NEVER made sense to me :x

Answer (score 2):

He was talking about that they are weak because they have their friends to hold them back. He's saying if they could just remain in solitude then their true potential will reveal itself.